# JSON data to React Table

Tags: json, reactjs

I am reading a Excel File as json objects.

Here is my Excel File.

[image]

I am reading excel data as json objects in the Inspect Tools as below.

[image]

I need to pass these json objects into a react table which can be selcted as row by row.

[image]

Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the excel data is shown in the inspect tools, we can set the data into the state and directly call them in the table.

```
 handleFiles = event => {
    var fileType = "xlsx";

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var extension = event.target.files[0].name
          .split(".")
          .pop()
          .toLowerCase(), //file extension from input file
        isSuccess = fileType.indexOf(extension) > -1; //is extension in acceptable types

      if (isSuccess) {
        //yes
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = event => {
          alert("Valid File extension");

          const bstr = event.target.result;

          const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });

          console.log("data>>>", wb);
          /* Get first worksheet */
          const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
          const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
          /* Convert array of arrays */

          const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

          //set  data into 
          this.setState({
            data: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws)
          });
          // ws;
          // { header: 1 }
          // );
          /* Update state */

          console.log("Data>>>", data);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
      } else {
        //no
        alert("Invalid File Type ");
      }
    }
  };
```

In the table it should be updated as below.

```
 <CheckboxTable 
     .............
                data={this.state.data}
      ........
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

To iterate over object you can do this,

```
const data = Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key,index) {
    // key: the name of the object key
    // index: the ordinal position of the key within the object 
    return (<tr><td>{obj[key]}</td>... //create td's as per your data</tr>)
});
```

In your component.

```
<Table>
   {data}
</Table>
```